# How can add some latex eq or symbol in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Gnuplot is power for plotting graph in scientific progress.

I have met this problem. I want to add some commands like `"$\ddot{x}$"`.

or `$\tau$` on the legend.

I see some people suggest that

```
plot [-5:5] [-1.5:1.5] sin(x+pi) title "$\\sin(x+\\pi)$"
```

But it seems it does not work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 24):

To get LaTeX in labels or legends in Gnuplot, you need to use one of the terminals that produce LaTeX code.

For example, you could use the `latex` terminal:

```
set terminal latex
set out 'plot.tex'
plot [-5:5] [-1.5:1.5] sin(x+pi) title "$\\sin(x+\\pi)$"
set out
```

That will produce a `plot.tex` file that includes the plot using basic TeX statements. You can include that file in your main document using `\input{plot.tex}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{plot.tex}
\end{document}
```

Which will give you

[image]

(notice that the quality isn't overwhelming when using the `latex` terminal).

You can also use the `epslatex` terminal:

```
set terminal epslatex color
set out 'plot.tex'
plot [-5:5] [-1.5:1.5] sin(x+pi) title "$\\sin(x+\\pi)$"
set out
```

This will include a `plot.tex` file with all the labels, and a separate `plot.eps` file including the graphical elements. You can include the output using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\input{plot.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could create the plots directly within LaTeX, using a package like PGFPlots or pst-plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits=false,
    legend entries=$\sin{x+\pi}$
]
\addplot [domain=-1.5*pi:1.5*pi, smooth] {sin(deg(x+pi))};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Method 1 is working, but I here got is a pdf document,then take a screenshot of pdf? Method 2, I got a .eps document but losing the title.

Comment: Method 2 is also working, but what I got is pdf document.

Comment: @JimmyWang: PDF is the output format of `pdflatex`. What format do you want?

Comment: I see. If I wanna put this graph in other document: one way is to get a screenshot, or directly put plot.tex and plot.eps in that main latex document. Is that right?

Comment: @JimmyWang: You just put `\input{plot.tex}` wherever you want the plot to appear.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `epslatex` terminal that comes with gnuplot. (There are some others like `cairolatex` that can do the same, but not all of them are included in a standard install.)

First you switch to the epslatex terminal, if it's not the standard terminal.

```
sett epslatex
```

Then you define the name of your output.

```
set output 'name.tex'
```

This will generate and empty `name.tex` file and once you plot your figure you'll get a `name.eps` file as well. You can also specify where the file should come by giving a path like `set output /users/yourname/desktop/name.tex`.
Now you can add LaTeX code to the axis labels. Once you're done you just plot with the standard plot command (and all the options you need). Type `set output` a last time to make sure everything it's written to the file you specified earlier.

Now you've ended up with a `.tex` file containing the all the numbers and labels for you axis and an `.eps` file that contains the actual plot. Put both of these files in the same folder as the `.tex` file in which you would like to put the plot. You can include these with the following code

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\input{name}
\end{figure}
```

This relies on the `graphicx` package and possibly on the `epstopdf` package if you're not using MacTex.

The beauty of this solution is that TeX renders all the labels and you can edit them by editing the `name.tex` file in which they're stored.