# Trying to use gnuplot to plot a simple graph with tex

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

I'm following this link word by word, using the epslatex terminal way:

[How can add some latex eq or symbol in gnuplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119518/how-can-add-some-latex-eq-or-symbol-in-gnuplot)

When I open up texworks, and run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\input{plot.tex}
\end{document}
```

I'm presented with

```
"! LaTeX Error: File `plot' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.96     \put(0,0){\includegraphics{plot}}
                                          %
? H
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit."
```

So basically it doesn't actually look for file extensions .tex? What am I missing? I have saved the .tex file in the same place as plot.tex and plot.eps. I'm fairly new to LaTex and even newer to gnuplot, so apologies if this is obvious.

Comment: My guess is you are compiling with `pdflatex` and not `latex`. `pdflatex` can handle lots of image formats but `eps`. `latex` can handle `eps` but not the common ones (`jpg`, `png`, etc.). I don't know how it works, but when I compile with `pdflatex` in ubuntu with TeXlive 2013, it runs something that converts the `eps` into a `pdf` and then uses the  `pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I compile with latex? I'm using texworks and the only options I have are pdflatex (which I was using originally using), luatex, xetex, context and bibtex.

Comment: Gnuplot is able to render `LaTeX` symbols in an `eps` file as well, however that file has to be converted to `pdf` format and then included with `pdflatex`. Doing this way, the included `figure` problably has to be rotated by 90 degrees. Note that, this is not an option, if the symbols are too complex.